# How to cURL multiple continuous pages in a "for" loop with PHP?

Tags: php, curl

For example, I want to curl 8 text files from http://example.com/0.txt to http://example.com/7.txt and echo them out, in a loop. The following is my current codes.

```
for ($i=0; $i < 6; $i++) { 
    $curl = curl_init();
    $post_url = 'http://example.com/' . i . '.txt';
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo '<article>' . $data . '</article>';
}
```

It seems that traditionally the value of key `CURLOPT_URL` is supposed to directly written in the 4th line, but the way doesn't meet my demand. I tried separating the string with two dots and inserting the loop-controlling variable `i` into the two strings, to form the third parameter, but it doesn't work.

Then I tried bring the statement out from the line, and set a variable in advance which combines two strings and one number variable and place the variable in the `curl_setopt()` function as the third parameter. It doesn't work.

By the time I search "php curl loop" or "curl in loop with parameter" or something else, Google can hardly provide me with helpful information.

So eventually I am seeking help here : (

Thanks in advance if anyone would like to offer solution.

Comment: What's the error message you're getting? I just tried your code and received all *6* (you have `$i < 6`, resulting in 0-5.txt) payloads back.

Comment: and it should be `. $i .` rather than `i`

Comment: teaching of the day: do not ignore notices/warnings from your compiler/interpreter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it can be because of typo but try fixing this & check,

```
$post_url = 'http://example.com/' . $i . '.txt'; // You miss '$' here
                                    ^
```

Comment: my php installation with all defaults gives a warning (Notice: Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' ...), so it produces `http://example.com/i.txt`. Surely this is an issue. Likely, it's the OP issue

Comment: As far as code post by OP, can't see any other issue than this. Better wait for OP's comment.

Comment: Okay now the issue is fixed... Anyway thank you! (*what a silly question